# Constant GPS status on or off Verification on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gps

I have an app which requires a constant gps status ON.Suppose inside app,I turned off my GPS.Now I want my App to show to enable gps again or else it should show force dialog.I hope you got the situation.I am not asking during opening app,gps on or off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code may help you..

Declare broadcast receiver

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {

        Log.e("GPS", "changed" + intent);

    }
}}
```

declare in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <receiver android:name=".GpsLocationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but you have declare one constant varible to moniter GPS Status . In GpsLocationReceiver give on changaed in GPS on or off but doesnot retrive on or off value so you have to declare static boolean variable to moniter it and if it is off then SHow your Dialog to Open GPS setting by below Code.

```
public void showSettingsAlert(){

     AlertDialog myAlertDialog;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    builder.setTitle("GPS settings");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    // Setting Dialog Message
    builder.setMessage("For Use This Application You Must Need to Enable GPS. do you want to go Setting menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    builder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });

    myAlertDialog = builder.create();

        myAlertDialog.show();


}
```

Comment: where did you declare that staic variable ? please post the complete code

Comment: yes,please post the whole code

Comment: Delcare static variable in Mainactivty like public static Boolean GPS_STATUS , and assign value in Receiver

Comment: Dixit,that guy is asking for full code,it would be deeply appreciate,if you could hep him by editing your code to full

Comment: @Cyborg91 There no any code but its my logic to check GPS setting chnaged Intent and by this we can check if its status changed